# Word or phrase for capitalizing pronouns referring to gods

Tags: expressions, capitalization, religion

Some publications capitalize *He*, *Him*, etc., when referring to a god.

What is this practice called? 'Proper noun' is rather generic.

Comment: *Elevation? Deification?*

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140777/are-pronouns-for-non-universal-divines-capitalized

Answer (score 3):

*[Reverential Capitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Pronouns)* (WP)

> Many European languages traditionally capitalize nouns and pronouns used to refer to God, including references to Jesus Christ (reverential capitals): *hallowed be Thy name, look what He has done.* Some English authors capitalize any word referring to God: *the Lamb*, *the Almighty*; some capitalize "Thy Name".