# Is it grammatically correct to capitalize pronouns referring to God

Tags: grammar, capitalization

In the bible, "he" and "his" are capitalized when they are used to refer to God. Is this grammatically correct? If so, what rule do we have that allows these words to be capitalized?

Comment: Yes, this is often done with pronouns referring to monotheist gods—at least by believers: non-believers will often not capitalise the pronouns. But anything is possible in either group.

Comment: Consult the practices of various religions to see how they like to do it. Each religion is a law unto themselves.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/133293/14666 Many European languages traditionally capitalize nouns and pronouns used to refer to God, including references to Jesus Christ (reverential capitals): hallowed be Thy name, look what He has done.